# How to access widget after being created by add_widget?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

When I use `add_widget`, and try to access it by using `ids`, I get a key error.

```
def create_rss(self, *args):
    for rss in "food", "wood", "stone", "iron", "gold":
        self.ids["res"].add_widget(ToggleButton(id=rss, text=rss))
        self.ids["res"].ids[rss].state = "down"
```

I expected to be able to change the state of the toggle button since it was being done before creating it with `add_widget`.

When trying to print the parent of the toggle button, I get nothing. So maybe add_widget its not making the togglebuttons the children of "res"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Question

> how can I access the button out side of the for loop?

### Solution

There are two methods for the solution.

#### Method 1 - Create own ids dictionary

This method involves creating our own `ids` dictionary type property. The advantages of this method are random and sequential access.

**Snippets**

```
from kivy.properties import DictProperty
...
class class-name(...):
    my_ids = DictProperty({})

    def create_rss(self, *args):
        for rss in "food", "wood", "stone", "iron", "gold":
            toggle_button = ToggleButton(id=rss, text=rss)
            self.my_ids[rss] = toggle_button
            self.ids["res"].add_widget(toggle_button)
            toggle_button.state = "down"

    def access_using_my_ids(self):
        print(f"\nsequential access:")
        for key, value in self.my_ids.items():
            print(f"key={key}, value={value}, text={value.text}")

        print(f"\nrandom access:")
        print(f"object={self.my_ids['stone']}, text={self.my_ids['stone'].text}")
```

#### Method 2 - Kivy Widget Tree

This method uses Kivy Widget Tree and a `for` loop to access the children. The disadvantages of this method is sequential access only.

**Snippets**

```
    for child in reversed(self.ids.res.children):
        if isinstance(child, ToggleButton):
            print(f"ToggleButton.text={child.text}")
```

## Kivy ids - created in Python script

Kivy `ids` created in Python script are not stored in `self.ids` dictionary type property. Therefore, one will get an error when trying to access it.

## Solution

Assign it to a variable.

### Snippets

```
def create_rss(self, *args):
    for rss in "food", "wood", "stone", "iron", "gold":
        toggle_button = ToggleButton(id=rss, text=rss)
        self.ids["res"].add_widget(toggle_button)
        toggle_button.state = "down"
```

Comment: how can I access the button out side of the for loop?

Comment: Please refer to updated post for solution to accessing `ToggleButton`s outside of the `for` loop.